# Not able to install modules with composer in Magneto 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, composer

I have installed Magento 2.3.1 and PHP 7.2.31, I am trying install modules with composer and getting error like below,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp0::initModuleDeployment() must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none returned in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code:69
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp0->initModuleDeployment(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#1 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(176): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#2 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#3 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(205): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('pre-update-cmd', true)
#4 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(20 in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code on line 69
```

Any solution on this?

Comment: i think this has something to do with your php version please check the compatibility

Comment: tried with PHP 7.1 also but still getting same error

Comment: try it with 7.3 could do the trick 7.1 life has already ended

Comment: PHP 7.3 is not support with Magento 2.3.1

Comment: i have just checked php 7.2 is supported with 2.3.1 so you php version is compatible

Comment: Yes PHP 7.2 is supported with Magento 2.3.1 but not supported with PHP 7.3

Comment: @Chikku after upgrade PHP 7.3.19 getting error like "An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned" in Magento 2.3.1

Comment: on your 7.2 php version try to run commands like this COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require company/module --no-plugins by adding COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 then your rest of the composer commands

Comment: let me know if this works for you

Comment: @Chikku as you mentioned i have run the command and getting error like  - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: get back to php 7.2 and then run it you will not get the error you posted here

Comment: tried with PHP 7.2 also and still getting error like :  magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement

Comment: @Chikku tried with PHP 7.2.31 also still getting same error :  magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement

Comment: then you are left with only one solution updated the packages that gave error one by one